# How to stop iCloud sync deleting photos on my pc?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, pc

Bought a new 2nd iPad for the kids - I deleted all photos (as Well as recently deleted photos)… But that was a mistake.

What I forgot to realize is that iCloud now started deleting the photos on all my units …

My PC was recently sync with iCloud so the photofolder still holds all the pictures.

But when I turn it on, and I gets online with iCloud it will start to deleted them during the sync (it did so on my laptop)… how do I stop that, and keep them on my PC? I have turned on my PC but made sure it does not have any internet access.

Help?

Comment: The prime error was in setting up your kids' pads on your ID. You should have set up their own accounts, then used [Family Sharing](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/) I'm not sure how to quickly rescue your synced photos, so I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: iCloud Photos is a sync service, not a backup.  It's doing exactly what it's designed to do. If you don't want the sync, you need to break the PC's connection to iCloud.  That may well remove them from the PC anyway, although I'd hope Apple isn't so incompetent that the software doesn't at least ask if you want to keep them.  Of course you have a backup of your pictures, so you can restore what might be missing.  Right?